# Why does react/javascript recreates a function instance every time we call it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

For example, onChange function:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const onChange = (e) => {
    doSomething(e.target.value)
  }

  return <input onChange={onChange} />
};
```

gets recreated on every change. Why is that, why can not the function keep the original reference?

Comment: You can maintain a single function instance with the useCallback hook

Comment: That's just how closures (functions defined inside functions) work. Why react chose to use this style is not known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React function components are just functions that run every render cycle and return JSX. So every render there's a completely different `onChange` constant that holds a different reference to the function(even though the behavior is the same).

If you want to keep the reference between renders, you should use `React.useCallback`. You can find more about it in React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: The syntax used for `useCallback` calls still re-creates the function object every time, it just doesn't return the new function from `useCallback` when the memoisation dependencies didn't change.